# Combining similar part of a string using Google Sheets functions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Please help me solve this problem. I'm trying to search all similar part of a string combine them then add all their numeric value at the beginning part of the string.

Input: cell A1

```
2 x Onsemi 3000K E27; 7 x Onsemi 3000K E27; 9 x Phoenix Eco 7W 4000K B22; 1 x Phoenix Eco 7W 4000K B22
```

Output: cell B1

```
9 x Onsemi 3000K E27; 10 x Phoenix Eco 7W 4000K B22
```

Tried using google match function but struggling on how to combine them then add the quantity.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN("; ", 1, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ";")), "(\d+)")*1,
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ";")), "\d+ (.*)")}, 
 "select sum(Col1),Col2 
  group by Col2 
  label sum(Col1)''", 0)),,999^99))))
```

[image: 0]